# Combining rows in CASE results

Tags: sql-server-2008

The below query is giving me the results that I want except for one minor issue. It lists everything correctly and in the proper order but I would like to combine the rows where the 'entity' is the same in the `faccount` groups and was looking for some advice on how to do so. As an example I will get

```
ROW1: 3010 (FACCOUNT)  clienta (Entity) 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 ....
ROW2: 3010 (FACCOUNT)  clienta (Entity) 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 ....
```

where ideally I would like one row for the same entity

```
ROW1: 3010 (FACCOUNT) clienta (Entity) 0 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 ....
```

Any thoughts are appreciated

```
SELECT CATEGORY,
ENTITY, 
FACCOUNT, 
SIGNEDDATA,
TIMEID,
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r1",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r2",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r4",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r5",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r6",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r7",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '7' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r8",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '8' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r9",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '9' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r10",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '10' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r11",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r12",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '12' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r13",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '13' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r14",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '14' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r15"

FROM [db1].[dbo].[tbl1]
WHERE Category = 'rdata' 
AND TIMEID BETWEEN 2013110000 AND 2013113100
GROUP BY ACCOUNT, ENTITY,CATEGORY, SIGNEDDATA, TIMEID
ORDER BY ACCOUNT, ENTITY
```

Answer (score 0):

1) The results does not contain the values ​​for `SIGNEDDATA, TIMEID` columns (`CATEGORY = 'rdata'`). For these columns you will see different values for the same `ACCOUNT` and `ENTITY`. If these columns are removed from `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` clauses then the values for `r1, r2, ... r15` will be *combined* (SUM). Also, I've seen that your query has two `Account` columns: `FACCOUNT` (`GROUP BY`) and `ACCOUNT`(`SELECT`).

```
SELECT CATEGORY,
ENTITY, 
FACCOUNT, 
/*SIGNEDDATA,
TIMEID,*/
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r1",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r2",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r4",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r5",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r6",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r7",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '7' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r8",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '8' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r9",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '9' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r10",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '10' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r11",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r12",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '12' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r13",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '13' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r14",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = '14' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "r15"

FROM [db1].[dbo].[tbl1]
WHERE Category = 'rdata' 
AND TIMEID BETWEEN 2013110000 AND 2013113100
GROUP BY FACCOUNT, ENTITY,CATEGORY/*, SIGNEDDATA, TIMEID*/
ORDER BY FACCOUNT, ENTITY
```

2) Another solution could be to use SUM with [OVER clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) but the *problem* of `SIGNEDDATA, TIMEID` columns remains:

```
SELECT CATEGORY,
ENTITY, 
FACCOUNT, 
SIGNEDDATA
TIMEID,
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY FACCOUNT, ENTITY) AS "r1",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY FACCOUNT, ENTITY) AS "r2",
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(SIGNEDDATA) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY FACCOUNT, ENTITY) AS "r3",
...
FROM [db1].[dbo].[tbl1]
WHERE Category = 'rdata' 
AND TIMEID BETWEEN 2013110000 AND 2013113100
ORDER BY FACCOUNT, ENTITY
```

Note: in this last case, the grouping is done by the `PARTITION BY`.